# Safe line IR laser which will be seen from 15 meters by camera module

Tags: power, infrared, camera, laser

[image: image 1]

What characteristics (wavelength, mW) IR line laser should have to:

1. be seen by camera module from 15 meters outdoor in day-light too
2. safe for eyes
3. line as big as possible
4. thickness of line should be enough to see from 15 meters 1280×720 camera

Camera characteristics:

1. 1280×720
2. 60 fps
3. I don't know what lens characteristic should be (relative to laser?)
4. I will use interference filter of laser wavelength

[Camera module itself](http://www.ebay.com/itm/5-Mega-pixel-Camera-Module-OV5642-1080P-JPEG-Output-/271130719953?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3f20a676d1)

As I understand it should be combination of lens and laser. Blind zone should be as small as possible.

Comment: This might not help but I read somewhere that the IR laser in the XBox Kinect is 780nm Class 1 (less than 25uW). I use an IR diode at 15m all the time (the TV remote!) The range under sunlight is a big issue though - once sunlight is falling on your sensor/camera/whatever, there will be too much IR to distinguish the emitter. I've used cardboard shields to prevent this but I'd also be very interested from other opinions on this.

Comment: Some cameras / lenses have IR cut filters, some don't. Check carefully.

Comment: @Dave Tweed: That's true, it is a comment and started out that way but thought it was too long for a comment. I suppose it dropped under the helpful answer line.

Comment: @JohnU i know, my camera will be without)

Comment: @carveone, interesting about the Kinect.  IR lasers are a lot more dangerous than visible ones because there is no blink reflex from the eye.  RE: IR LED's and sunlight.  Can you blink the LED and do synchronous detection?  Even just blinking and a moderate (Q~10) band pass filter would help.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold is 5mW Line IR laser is dangerous for eyes? My laser will rotate 360 degrees for 1-2 secs, step is 3 degree, line is vertical, is it dangerous? If yes, what wattage i should use?

Comment: @Kracken,  First I'm not a laser safety guy, so I don't know the exact details.  Does a line laser mean that the beam is expanded in one direction to make line.  So the question is how much power can be collected by the eye.  I know that 1 mW into the eye is enough to cause damage.  (Think about looking at the sun, it's ~1kW/m^2.. and the eye pupil is 1 mm^2.)  So what's the minimum level that can cause damage.  I just don't know.  What happens if the laser stops rotating?

Comment: By "line as big as possible", do you mean like 36" (1m) wide? 3m wide? If so, a laser is vast overkill - you could use a simpler (non-laser) IR source shining through a slit. With a beam spread that wide, there'd be very little worry about eye safety. You could modulate the IR source (pulsed, for example, at 20Hz) to make it easier to distinguish from sunlight.

Comment: @TDHofstetter, thanks for answer. I need this for 3D scanning. "As big as possible" i mean line length. Thickness should be 40-90mm at 15 meters. And i will use camera as detector, i can't modulate camera module

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to put this as an answer, it feels more like a comment. (they are getting too long)

If I was designing a laser system for outdoor use with public access, then I'd have to assume a worse case scenario.  In this case that would be some idiot sticking a screw driver into the spinning mechanism, stopping it, and then looking in to see how it works.  In which case 5mW is too much.  25 uW sound's like a safe number.